# Stop redirecting mobile site on iPad

Tags: php, user-agent

I have to two site one is my main site and otherone is for mobile site.This is the script i am using for redirecting the site on mobile when it is being used in mobile device. Now i want to ignore the mobile site redirection for iPad. I have used this script but its not ignoring iPad it still redirecting on mobile site on Ipad and i dont want this. Plz help.

```
 <?php
    function check_user_agent ( $type = NULL ) {
            $user_agent = strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
            if ( $type == 'bot' ) {
                    // matches popular bots
                    if ( preg_match ( "/googlebot|adsbot|yahooseeker|yahoobot|msnbot|watchmouse|pingdom\.com|feedfetcher-google/", $user_agent ) ) {
                            return true;
                            // watchmouse|pingdom\.com are "uptime services"
                    }
            } else if ( $type == 'browser' ) {
                    // matches core browser types
                    if ( preg_match ( "/mozilla\/|opera\//", $user_agent ) ) {
                            return true;
                    }
            } else if ( $type == 'mobile' ) {
                    // matches popular mobile devices that have small screens and/or touch inputs
                    // mobile devices have regional trends; some of these will have varying popularity in Europe, Asia, and America
                    // detailed demographics are unknown, and South America, the Pacific Islands, and Africa trends might not be represented, here


                   if( preg_match ( "/iPad/", $user_agent )) {
                            return false;
                    }  else if ( preg_match ( "/phone|iphone|itouch|ipod|symbian|android|htc_|htc-|palmos|blackberry|opera mini|iemobile|windows ce|nokia|fennec|hiptop|kindle|mot |mot-|webos\/|samsung|sonyericsson|^sie-|nintendo/", $user_agent ) ) {
                            // these are the most common
                            return true;
                    } else if ( preg_match ( "/mobile|pda;|avantgo|eudoraweb|minimo|netfront|brew|teleca|lg;|lge |wap;| wap /", $user_agent ) ) {
                            // these are less common, and might not be worth checking
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    }
    $ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
    if($ismobile) {
    header('Location:mobiles_site_url');
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: At some point [CSS3 media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) will have widespread support, and this sort of code will no longer be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `strtolower()` on the user agent string and the first line to check for the 'iPad' has an uppercase letter in it.

Try:

```
if( preg_match ( "/ipad/", $user_agent )) {  // all lower case
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks its look like it will work....do you have ipad to test for me as i dont have...:)

Comment: I do.  The agent user string is: `mozilla/5.0 (ipad; cpu os 5_1_1 like mac os x) applewebkit/534.46 (khtml, like gecko) version/5.1 mobile/9b206 safari/7534.48.3`  AFTER strtolower() was called on it.  So, the lowercase 'ipad' is in the string so it should work fine.

Comment: ya i can understand this. but can you please open this http://mypartyaid.com/ url it should not redirect on http://mypartyaid.com/m . Please let me know about this...Thanks :)